# Android Navigation Drawer and Recycler View in the same activity

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I have a navigation drawer in my MainActivity. I also use Recycler Views to display a list of products to the MainActivity. How can I get the different items of the navigation drawer to click? I think the problem is in the structure of the activity_main.xml file. Here is the code for my activity_main.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".controller.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".controller.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_main_header_special_discount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_main_header_articles"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewVertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the code for the drawer in my MainActivity.java file :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.home :
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.createAccount :
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Create account selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.login:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Log in selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the menu file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
            android:title="Home"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/login"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_login_24"
            android:title="Log in"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/createAccount"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_create_24"
            android:title="Create account"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```